# Is it possible for a HashMap key to be associated with an element in a Linked List?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, hashmap

I have a linked list of Car objects.
Some cars need to have a DriverLicense object associated with them (this would be the key).

How can I do this?

Comment: Adding `DriverLicence` as a property of car?

Comment: I've been told not to do this. It must be a Map of some sort.

Comment: Without more info, you were told wrong. This is what objects are all about.

Comment: While I don't know why you have this constraint, there's a convenient data structure called a "LinkedHashMap" you could use.

Comment: That's how I would have done it, but I've got to follow their specification if I'm going to get the marks. :)

Maybe it's because not all cars have a driver's license associated with them.

Comment: Well, in truth, a `Car` doesn't have a `DriverLicense`. It is the `Driver` that has it.

Comment: And each `Driver` is going to have a `Licence`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything in Java is object reference. Any objects can be used as key for the MAP however the key need to be immutable.